# Java: Make only 1 radio button switched at a time (RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android

As a title says, I need to make my radio buttons to be able to have only 1 selected at a time.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class NewGameCourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewGameCourseAdapter.NewGameCourseViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<NewGameCourseItem> mCourseList;
    private NewGameCourseAdapter.OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener;

    private int checkedItems = 0;

    public void setOnItemsCheckStateListener(OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener2) {
        this.checkStateListener = checkStateListener2;
    }

    public interface OnItemsCheckStateListener {
        void onItemCheckStateChanged(int checkedItemCounter);
    }
```

onBindViewHolder:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewGameCourseViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final NewGameCourseItem currentItem = mCourseList.get(position);

        /** This can prevent some unwanted actions in some cases **/
        holder.mRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        /** If true, radio button will be selected, else unselected **/
        holder.mRadioButton.setChecked(currentItem.getRadioButton());

        holder.mRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                /** set object's last status **/
                currentItem.setSelected(isChecked);

                if (isChecked) {
                    checkedItems++;
                } else {
                    checkedItems--;
                }

                checkStateListener.onItemCheckStateChanged(checkedItems);
            }
        });
```

I used this same method witch checkboxes, and I thought that maybe I can manage to use it with this too, with some little changes.
What should I do/change in order to make a single selection working here?
How do I make it change previous selection false?

Comment: use RadioGroup for that

Comment: How can I get all these items into 1 group?

Comment: Radio buttons? you are saying

Comment: Yeah but ofc those radio buttons are all in separated items within same recyclerview

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the position of the item with the selected button and update its state (by changing the boolean value in the element of your data list and then calling `notifyItemChanged(position)` when another button is clicked. And update this position after all, of course

Comment: I have been trying this:                 if (isChecked) {
                    checkedItems++;
                    currentItem.setSelected(isChecked);
                } else {
                    checkedItems--;
                    currentItem.setSelected(false);
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged(); But obviously not manage to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

**Use arrayList of data that your are passing**

```
    //final List<CheckBox> allChkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    //allChkBoxes.add(holder.chkBox);

    holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    for(int i =0 ; i < arryList.size(); i ++){
                        //The postion which you get on OnClick is compared with all CheckBoxes added to List
                        if(i == position){
                            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
                        }else {
                            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false); //Clear check
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: its a for loop bro.. get postion of clicked item and check the item through those listview.. add all checkboxes to list and check through for loop

Comment: I made just like you did, but only the first box in a list checks when clicked, others won't even tho I'm clicking them

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using radibuttons instead of checkboxes

Comment: allChkBoxes.size(); check size that all checkboxes added or not

Comment: allChkBoxes.add(holder.chkBox); Could this only add the first 1 to the list, and thats why it only checks that first1?

Comment: instead of CheckBox arraylist take those ArrayList Of data you are using..